# Multiple accounts for same website in 1Password

Tags: 1password

There are websites on which I have multiple accounts, for example Twitter: private account and work account. 1Password lists accounts in a certain order, possibly alphabetical.  When I press *⌘-#* in my web browser, data from the first account is auto-filled.

Since I use my private account almost all of the time, but 1Password chooses to auto-fill the data of my work account, is there a way to define a "default" account for a given website?

I could of course rename the accounts within 1Password, but I'd like to know if the app itself provides this functionality. I searched the help file but couldn't find anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no such functionality, but you could try the workaround below:

> 1. Open the main 1Password app and select one of the Logins for a site
>      that you don't want to set as the default.
> 2. Click 'Edit' at the bottom of the window and click the 'Display'
>      menu that appears.
> 3. Choose "Never Display in Browser", then click Save at the bottom of
>      the window.
> 4. Repeat these steps for each of the Logins you don't want to set as
>      the default.

You'll still be able to access your work account from the app. It just won't be available in the browser you're using.

**Source:** [Can I set a default login for a website](https://discussions.agilebits.com/discussion/12009/can-i-set-a-default-login-for-a-website)